# Can't import google.golang.org/grpc and github.com/dgraph-io/dgo in Go code

Tags: go, dgraph

I am trying to import `github.com/dgraph-io/dgo` and `google.golang.org/grpc` in my `Go` code.
But when I save the file it gets removed.
This is how I am trying :

```
import (
     "bytes"
     "encoding/json"
     "fmt"
     "io/ioutil"
     "net/http"
     
     "google.golang.org/grpc"
     "github.com/dgraph-io/dgo"
)
```

I tried to get `github.com/dgraph-io/dgo` package using command `go get github.com/dgraph-io/dgo`

Can anyone please help what is prerequisite to use given packages.
My aim is to use `Dgraph` queries and Mutations in Go

Comment: You probably have `goimports` as part of your save hook and you are not using the packages in your code, so it just removes them.

Comment: Go does not allow unused imports: if you do not reference `dgo` in the file's code, that file won't compile. As @Marc suggested, if your IDE runs `goimports`—a popular tool to guess which packages need to be imported (by looking at the package references in the code)—upon saving the file, that would indeed explain the observed behaviour.

Comment: Still note that _some_ packages might indeed need to be imported even if they're not directly used—for side effectes of their initialization. These days this is considered to be an anti-pattern and bad practice but, say, drivers for `database/sql` has to behave this way. If _and only if_ `dgo` is indeed such a package (and you have to figure that out in its docs) you need to use `import _ "github.com/dgraph-io/dgo"`—that is import the package as the `_` identifier. But, again, please check the docs first.